# Form is being converted to table in iPad iOs

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

I am currently using jquery.fileDownload.js to export the csv file from browsers which is working fine in all browsers except iOS. This js includes function `checkFileDownloadComplete()` which checks for file downloaded or not.

In iOS, csv file is being rendered on another tab of browser which is fine. But the above mentioned function checks whether file has been downloaded completely or it has faced any errors. Here the error string is always being displayed irrespective of file has been downloaded or not.

The problem is I am posting a form to the server in the new blank window and then checking the same form again in the response. But the form has been changed to a table in order to render it on iOS. How to fix this? Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
if ($form && $form.length) {
    var $contents = $(formDoc.body).contents().first();
    if ($contents.length && $contents[0] === $form[0]) {
        isFailure = false;
    }
}
```

This `$contents[0]` gives me table whereas `$form[0]` gives me form.

Answer (score 0):

There's a quick fix in order to achieve ajax like file downloading,

Just create two methods

1. First one which will receive the parameters based on which the file will be generated on the server and will return the guid name of the file and in-case some error it will throw an exception which can be taken up on front-end like some error occurred while downloading.
2. Second one will be the method which will just serve the static file.

This way you can achieve the same feature of ajax like file download.